# Как сравнить элемент string и char?

Tags: c++

Не могу понять как сравнить элемент строки и char. Вот участок программы:

```
for (int i = 0; i < temp.size(); i++)
{
    if (temp[i] == ", ")
    {
        continue;
    }
    else
    {
        while (temp[i] != ", ")
        {
            tempTwo += temp;
        }
        games.push_back(tempTwo);
    }
}
```

Все операторы сравнения в данном случае подчеркнуты. Вот целый код:

```
//game list
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "iostream"
#include "string"
#include "vector"
#include "algorithm"
#include "conio.h"
#include "fstream"
using namespace std;

void main()
{
    int choice, answer;
    vector<string> games;
    vector<string>::const_iterator iter;
    string temp = "";
    string tempTwo;
    ifstream read;
    read.open("c:\\self\\list.txt");
    if (read.is_open())
    {
        while (getline(read, temp))
        {
            read.close();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "File cannot be read." << endl;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < temp.size(); i++)
    {
        if (temp[i] == ", ")
        {
            continue;
        }
        else
        {
            while (temp[i] != ", ")
            {
                tempTwo += temp;
            }
            games.push_back(tempTwo);
        }
    }
    cout << "Welcome!" << endl;
    cout << "1 - Add the game" << endl;
    cout << "2 - Remove the game" << endl;
    cout << "3 - List of the games\n\n";
    cout << "My choice is ";     
    cin >> choice;                                                                                                                                              
    while (choice < 1 && choice > 3)
    {
        cout << "Wrong choice! Try again: ";
        cin >> choice;
    }
    if (choice == 1)
    {
        string newGame;
        cout << "Enter the name of the game you want to be added: ";
        cin >> newGame;
        games.push_back(newGame);
        ofstream toList;
        toList.open("c:\\self\\list.txt");
        for (iter = games.begin(); iter < games.end(); ++iter)
        {
            toList << *iter << ",";
        }
        cout << newGame << " was successfully added.";
    }
    else if (choice == 2)
    {
        if (!games.empty())
        {
            if (games.size() == 1)
            {
                cout << games[0] << endl;
                cout << "Do you want to remove this game?" << endl;
            }
            else
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < games.size(); i++)
                {
                    cout << "Select the game you want to be removed";
                    cout << i + 1 << " - " ;
                    cout << games[i] << endl;
                }
                cin >> answer;
                games.erase(games.begin() + answer - 1);
                ofstream remove;
                remove.open("c:\\self\\list.txt");
                for (iter = games.begin; iter < games.end(); iter++)
                {
                    remove << *iter << ", ";
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Cannot remove any games because the list is empty.";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (!games.empty())
        {
            if (games.size() == 1)
            {
                cout << "1 - ";
                cout << games[0] << endl;
            }
            else
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < games.size(); i++)
                {
                    cout << i + 1 << " - ";
                    cout << games[i] << endl;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Cannot list the games because the list is empty." << endl;
        }
    }
    _getch();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`", "` это не `char`, а `char[3]{',', ' ', 0}`(т.е. массив `char` из трёх элементов, где последним элементом является нуль-символ). Чтобы получить `char` нужно использовать одинарные кавычки, т.е. в Вашем случае, чтобы получить символ запятой, нужно написать `','`. В остальном, Ваша проверка выглядит верно.

Comment: Спасибо, помогло. Теперь ругается в `for (int i = 0; i < games.size(); i++)`, как я понял ошибка в signed/unsigned сравнении. Не подскажешь в чем проблема? @ixSci

Comment: @vdublevsky, ругается в смысле warning? Да, может быть, `size()` возвращает объект типа `size_t`(он беззнаковый и может быть больше `int`), поэтому используйте `size_t` для `i`, и warning уйдёт.

Comment: а вот здесь не поможешь? [imgur](http://imgur.com/6W1idTf) ругается на эту строку кода `for (iter = games.begin; iter < games.end(); iter++)`

Comment: @vdublevsky, читайте внимательно сообщения об ошибках: у вас ошибка в получение begin-итератора. `begin` это функция, поэтому должно быть `iter = games.begin()`

Comment: Спасибо, совсем не заметил нехватки скобок.